# Detect iOS7 Safari browser with php

Tags: php, safari, ios7, version

Because of the new version of Safari, and of some CSS rules changed, my webapp don't do things correctly.
This WebApp adjust CSS in JavaScript.

Changes that cause problem (CSS) :

```
-webkit-filter: brightness(30%)";
-webkit-filter: brightness(0%)";
-webkit-filter: brightness(-30%)";
```

Become in iOS7 Safari version :

```
-webkit-filter: brightness(130%)";
-webkit-filter: brightness(100%)";
-webkit-filter: brightness(70%)";
```

So i'd like to load a specific JavaScript on iOS7+/Safari, else the actual file will be loaded.

I saw some solutions in JavaScript, but i'd like to do this with PHP, to optimise the weight of my WebApp.

(Sorry if my english isn't perfect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this php class.
http://techpatterns.com/downloads/php_browser_detection.php
I've tried using php browscap.ini but it hardly detects iOS 7